# Download the image by url , or convert it with base64

Tags: android, json, image, base64

My app receive a jsonArray that contain names of categories and their images urls. which is the best to do:

1. send the url of the images and after that download them.
2. or instead of sending the url I will send the images converted with base64.
   actually I know that base64 is more larger, but I just want to do a trade off between the size and the number of the requests, I mean which is better: to get one large request, or get a lot of small request ?

I have about 20 categories and the image is just 20-30 Kb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: Send the image urls and download and heavily cache device side, this tends to 'Always' be the best way.

The JSON response should have an array of your objects each with a name and a URL, simply get the JSON response in your app and parse out the relevant URLS and names, downloading each using Picasso (As discussed in earlier question) as you go, it will cache them for faster access in future also.